# Get the Value Of Dynamically Added Textbox in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have added some Textbox Controls in a grideview on RowDataBound event as :

```
protected void gvPriceRange_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtRange = null;
    DataTable dtTemplateType = null;
    try
    {
        dtRange = (DataTable)Session["dtRange"];
        dtTemplateType = (DataTable)Session["dtTemplateType"];
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtPrice = new TextBox();
                txtPrice.ID = "txtPrice" + i;
                e.Row.Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(txtPrice);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on button click Event , i have to save the textBox values in DB.

```
protected void btnSavePriceRange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtRange = null;
    DataTable dtTemplateType = null;
    MailingProgram mp = null;
    try
    {
        mp = new MailingProgram();
        dtRange = (DataTable)Session["dtRange"];
        dtTemplateType = (DataTable)Session["dtTemplateType"];

        foreach(GridViewRow row in gvPriceRange.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtPrice = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtPrice"+i);
                if (txtPrice != null)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i am not getting any reference for the textbox.
watch at row like 'row.Cells[1].HasControls()' is returning false , means no textBox is beign rendered by the gridview.
How could i get the reference for the Textbox ?

Comment: I think you're not getting any value because the ID is rendered differently.  You should just find the tstPrice ID in the row you are looking at - that should give you the value.

Comment: Perhaps it's due to adding to cells: `e.Row.Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(txtPrice);` but trying to get from row: `(TextBox)row.FindControl("txtPrice"+i);`?

Comment: @Dean.DePue - in Html , ID is generating Properly. But,reference of the textBox ID is null.

Comment: @DaveParsons - I have also tried  TextBox txtPrice = (TextBox)gvPriceRange.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[i+1].FindControl("txtPrice"+i);   But no luck. Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Are you rebinding your `GridView` on postback? If I recall correctly dynamically created controls are not preserved when posting back. You need to add them again then `ViewState` (I think) will deal with setting their state appropriately.

Comment: What happens when you do not add the "i" to the ID of the textbox?  Does it display properly?  Can you access the box in the row with just the ID then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Find Controls in GridView on Dynamic Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737710/cant-find-controls-in-gridview-on-dynamic-controls)

Comment: @HazemAbdelWahab Good job, identifying a 2014 question as duplicate of a 2015 question ;) Still good you reference something with an answer.