# Can't Find Controls in GridView on Dynamic Controls

Tags: vb.net, gridview, dynamic-controls

I have a gridview where I add textboxes to everycell on runtime. However, I can't seem to access those controls using `findcontrol`

Here is how I add the textboxes to the gridview:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For i = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1

            Dim txtSchedule As New TextBox()

            txtSchedule.ID = "txtSchedule" & i.ToString

           e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(txtSchedule)
        Next
    End If
```

When I go to find the controls it says they are Nothing :

```
GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(cellindex).FindControl("txtSchedule" & cellindex.ToString)
```

**EDIT**
The problem is that after the textboxes get populated it recreates the textboxes since I have them in row created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FindControl within the Cell of the Row that you added the Control:

```
GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(cellindex).FindControl("txtSchedule" & cellindex.ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is now that it adds the textboxes on row created, and after I populate those textboxes it recreates them

Comment: Do you mean it makes duplicate textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamically added textbox doesn't exist in fact. Thus, you cannot access or find it. You can add your textbox physically inside the grid **TemplateField** and set its **visibility** to **false** like the code segment below:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>                     
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

After that, and if you want, you can find the textbox and toggle its visibility from code behind.